# Recursive function for min-heap binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have been stuck on solving this task for quite a while. I need to write a recursive function to check whether that every node is smaller than any of its children. Returns true if the binary tree is a min-heap and false otherwise.

What i have so far:

```
def min_heap(t):
    if t == None:
        return True
    else:
        return t.left.value > t.value and t.right.value > t.value
```

Comment: "I have been stuck on solving this task for quite a while" - show us what you have

Comment: Is that recursive? There is a base case, OK, but there is no call to itself in no point?

Answer (score 1):

If it's recursive, that means it should be calling itself. Assuming your min-heap by definition is

> every node is smaller than any of its children

```
def min_heap(t):
    if t == None:
        return True
    if t.left and t.value > t.left.value:
        return False
    if t.right and t.value > t.right.value:
        return False
    return min_heap(t.left) and min_heap(t.right)
```

Comment: In the second and third if statements, aren't t.left and t.right trees?

Comment: yes, `if t.left` just makes sure that it's not `None`. Otherwise `t.left.value` would fail.

Comment: ooh ok. So that code is the same as `if t.left != None and t.value > t.left.value:`?

Comment: yes exactly. But you should write that as `t.left is not None`

Comment: Why is it better to write it that way?